# How do you set the keyboard hook timeout value for VMware Workstation for Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, vmware-workstation

Every time I start VMware Workstation I get a dialog asking to "update the value" of the keyboard hook timeout value.

[image: Vmware dialog]

Clicking OK works for that session but checking "Do not show this message again" has no effect. The dialog pops up again the next time VMware workstation is started.

How do I set the correct timeout value so it will quit asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Regedit and navigate to

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\
>   [image: regedit]

Find the DWORD key called **LowLevelHooksTimeout**.
Edit the decimal value to 5000.
[image: edit lowlevelhooks]

Click OK and close Registry Editor.
Next time VMware Workstation starts up it won't ask about the keyboard hook timeout value.